# Parse dynamic variable name and count in json

Tags: java, json, gson

JSON:

```
{ 
    id: "val", 
    name: "val", 
    var1: "val", 
    var2: "val",
    ... 
    var#: "val" 
}
```

In PHP I whould write something like:

```
while(isset(${"var".$i++}))
```

But how parse this in Java (using gson) ... its possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible. What would you like to parse it into?

Comment: all vars to 1 ArrayList

Comment: Use `Gson` or `Jackson` or _any_ other JSON parser and parse the data into a `Map<String, String>`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider ok I will parse all data in Map and how I then move all var# variables to arraylist ?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Either you have a number of variables _or_ you have an array. JSON has a representation of an array and any good parser will parse that to a `List` automatically. If you have invalid JSON then you will have to mangle it yourself.

Comment: I know but its not my fault that json look like that ... ofc it would be better and more logic that vars was in array but they are not, thats why I asking how to solve it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use Google Json Parsing API (Gson) to parse some dynamic fields in my json?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818567/how-do-i-use-google-json-parsing-api-gson-to-parse-some-dynamic-fields-in-my-j)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just interested in pulling out values and are not relying on any data binding, you could just use the Gson parser to parse the JSON tree and just walk it yourself.

The sample code would look like the following.

```
JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement tree = jsonParser.parse(json_input);

// now you can walk it
JsonObject document = tree.getAsJsonObject();

//check if -- is set
document.has("var1");

// get the value
document.get("var1").getAsString()

// assuming your identifiers are are all consecutively numbered
for (int i = 1; document.has("var" + i); i++)
    document.get("var" + i).getAsString();
}

// or to mimic your example - at the expense of readability
int i = 0;
while (document.has("var" + ++i)) {
    document.get("var" + i).getAsString();
}
```

Comment: +1. You could even recreate the OP's original syntax almost exactly - `for(int i = 0; document.has("var" + i); ++i){}`

Comment: Cool, and gson can check if exist key name?

Comment: Yes ... that's what the code uses. You might need to adjust the code depending on what the value of "varX" is. I just assume a string value.

Comment: Oooh, my bad, I though `JsonParser` and `JsonElement` is from `json.org` library ... ok im gonna test it and then I accept answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is you can use something like this.

```
var i = 1;
while (typeof e("data.var" + i) != 'undefined') {
  // DO STUFF
  i++
}
```

I question on why this is necessary though, it would be easier to make var1 and var2 into an array eg

```
{ 
id: "val", 
name: "val", 
myVar: [
        {"1" : "val", 
        {"2" : "val"}
       ],
... 
var#: "val" 
}
```

and then you could just use foreach and (I think) you would get a performance boost if you have lots of i

Comment: I cant change json structure

Comment: gutted for you, tell who ever it is that it's bad though :) the top example should work though.